# Wireless microcontroller setup for small hd display?

Tags: microcontroller

I need to know what is the smallest microcontroller setup I can get away for a small hd display running off battery? The board ideally should be flatter rather than compact if thats possible and needs to understand commands to the display from a bluetooth module, so that the screen is being controlled wirelessly. Suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: Microcontroller for HD display? Even for 1280x720 16 bit color - one frame needs almost 2MB of memory. **Thats not the job for microcontroller**. For FullHD and 24 bit color you need more than 6MB memory.

Comment: what would be needed to run the display?

Comment: A raspberry pi?

Comment: You have suggested a solution to your problem rather than describing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buidling device for wireless HD image transmission is pretty challenging and too hard for enthusiasts. Intel developeed such technology, it's called WiDi (wireless display).

There are devices with WiDi available on the market (search on google or ebay for WiDi).

I think microcontrollers are too weak for such application.

Thats also too much data to transfer over bluetooth.

Bluetooth 3.1 (fastest?) can transfer 40 Mb/s (megabits). Thats 5MB (megabytes).

**One 1920x1080 frame** with 24 bit color is 1920x1080x24 = 49766400 bits, so about ~50Mb (megabits) or **6.22MB** (megabytes). To transfer that frame over bluetooth you will need more than 1 second.

To transfer 30 frames per second without compression you need 1.5Gb (gigabit) transfer...

It can be done, but you will get less than 1 frame per second.

To get better framerate - you have to compress image at transmitter and decompress it in recevier. Compressing image in realtime requires significant computing power. Im not sure if any microcontroller is able to do that, however I may be wrong, im not familiar with 32-bit microcontrollers.